# How to automatically return the value after the last chained method with Builder pattern without build method?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, builder, method-chaining

I want my methods to return value instead of the class instance if that's the last chained method.

For example normally we have this:

```
class MyClass {
   constructor(){
    this.value = 0;
   }

   plus(amount){
     this.value += amount;
     return this;
   }

   minus(amount){
     this.value -= amount;
     return this;
   }

   getNumber(){
     return this.value;
   }
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
class MyClass {
   constructor(){
    this.value = 0;
   }

   plus(amount){
     this.value += amount;
     if(isLastMethod){    // How do I know if that's the last method ?
       return this.value;
     } else{
       return this;
     }

   }

   minus(amount){
     this.value -= amount;
     if(isLastMethod){
       return this.value;
     } else{
       return this;
     }
   }
}
```

It would be even better if I can call more methods on the returned value, but at least this conditional return based on whether the method is last or not would be great.

Comment: *"How do I know if that's the last method ?"*: you don't.

Comment: But what's wrong with `let c = new MyClass(); c.add(10).minus(2).value;`

Comment: Hint: You _do know_ if it's the last call every time someone calls `getNumber` ;) Honestly: You cannot know in advance if any method is the last method that will be called, because you don't know the exact order in which someone (besides yourself) who uses your class calls the methods.

Comment: Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Answer (score 0):

As we do not whether it is the last method, but we can add parameter `returnValue` to get value from the method and set it to true if you want to get value immediately:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
   this.value = 0;
  }

  plus(amount, returnValue){
    this.value += amount;
    if (returnValue)
      return this.value

    return this;
  }

  minus(amount, returnValue){
    this.value -= amount;
    if (returnValue)
      return this.value

    return this;
  }

  getNumber(){
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

An example can be seen here:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
   this.value = 0;
  }

  plus(amount, returnValue){
    this.value += amount;
    if (returnValue)
      return this.value

    return this;
  }

  minus(amount, returnValue){
    this.value -= amount;
    if (returnValue)
      return this.value

    return this;
  }

  getNumber(){
    return this.value;
  }
}

let myClass = new MyClass();
let value = myClass.plus(8).minus(1, true)
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create such builder this way

```
function builderMyClass(builderFunc) {
  const myClass = new MyClass();
  const builder = {
    plus: (value) => {
      myClass.plus(value);
      return builder;
    },
    minus: (value) => {
      myClass.minus(value);
      return builder;
    },
  };
  builderFunc(builder);
  return myClass.getNumber();
}
```

and the usage

```
const result = builderMyClass((builder) => 
  builder
    .plus(5)
    .minus(4)
    .plus(1)
);
```